# Can I deselect something in MS Word that had earlier been selected in the program

Tags: c#, ms-word

I have a piece of code where as part of some event handling I am selecting an image in a word document and copying it in a file. But after the event handler is done, the image is shown as selected when I return back to word after the event has been handled.
The code snippet is as follows :

```
foreach (Word.InlineShape shape in shapes)
{
    string filepath = "somepath";
    shape.Select();
    Word.Application application = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
    application.Selection.CopyAsPicture();
    Computer comp = new Computer();
    Image image = comp.Clipboard.GetImage();
    image.Save(filepath, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    comp.Clipboard.Clear();
}
```

I want that this shape should not be shown as selected because the shape selection was only part of some event handling.

Is there a way to deselect this shape.

Thanx for your suggestions.

Comment: Did you try `Selection.Collapse()`?

Answer (score 6):

You deselect the current selection by using

```
application.Selection.Collapse()
```